# onClick function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, the following code does not work properly:

```
<input onclick="$(function(){ alert($(this).attr('checked')); })" name="step1[agree]" id="step1_agree" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

It alerts with `undefined`. I have also tried doing something like this:

```
onclick="$(function(){ var chk=$(this); alert(chk.attr('id')); })"
```

... but ends up with the same result. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input onclick="alert($(this).attr('checked'));" name="step1[agree]" id="step1_agree" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

But a better option would be

```
<input name="step1[agree]" id="step1_agree" value="1" type="checkbox">

$('#step1_agree').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('checked));
});
```

Comment: Please prepend `#` to your selector

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
onclick="alert(this.checked);"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please learn about [binding](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) in jQuery.

```
$('#step1_agree').bind('click', function() {
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are wrapping it in a function like that. It should just be

`onclick="alert($(this).attr('id'));"`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [**unobtrusive javascript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

You can use something like

```
$(function(){
    $("#step1_agree").click(function(){
       alert (this.checked); 
    });
});
```

`$(function(){
});` gets fired once the DOM is ready.

You must assign all event handlers inside document ready. You can use an [**`id selector`**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to attach a [**`click event handler`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the desired element. To get the checked attribute you can use the native javascript code [**`this.checked`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/checked).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
$('#step1_agree').click(function(){
alert('')
});
}) 
</script>
```